# Excel VBA: automatically adjust tab colour

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell ("L2") that is controlled with an if function to determine either "PASS", "ERROR" or "CHECK BOX" based on user input in other fields.

I want the colour of that respective tab to change automatically based on cell content whenever the value of cell L2 changes.

My code currently looks like this, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can you please have a look and help me out? Many thanks for your help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(False, False) = "L2" Then

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "ERROR"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
        Case "PASS"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
        Case Else
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End Select

End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:

I noticed something interesting: As the displayed value of cell "L2" is controlled via an if function that is contained within it, the vba does not appear to read the displayed value, but rather the if-statement from the cell. How can I get around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where does the error occur and what message do you get?

Comment: no error occurs, but the change does not occur.

Comment: Your code is ok, doing what you need. You must be sure that you test it in exactly the same sheet where your code belongs to (Sheet module in VBA/IDE).

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code, step through with `F8` and see what happens. Suspect you're hitting `Case Else`.

Comment: The code is definitely allocated to the right sheet. How do I put a breakpoint? I'm sorry, my VBA is very basic at best.

Comment: Open the code window `ALT + F11` then click on the grey bar on the left of a code line. It'll highlight the line and put a circle in the bar. Now when you run the code, it will stop at that line. Pressing `F8` will walk through the code, one line at a time.

Comment: Ok I noticed something interesting: Whenever I manually enter data into "L2", then the code works. But it does not work when the cell is updated automatically via changes in other cells. How can I get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want the tab color to change depending on the value in the L2 then use this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Range("$L$2").Value
        Case "ERROR"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
        Case "PASS"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
        Case Else
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End Select
End Sub
```