# Dynamic tab colours issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have attempted various iterations of the below and some have worked first time around, then not after, some not at all.

In short cell b2 on all sheets can be one of 6 text entries, (complete, in progress, scrapped, future works, parked, held) to show the currwnt state of that specific piece of work. To further help at a glance I want to update tab colours based on b1 as well.i.e if in progress B2 goes green, so does that tab.

Current code:

```
Private Sub tabcolour_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

             Select Case Range("$b$2").Value
            Case "In progress"
                .Color = 43
            Case "Held"
                .Color = 6
            Case "Scrapped"
                .Color = 3
            Case "Parked"
                .Color = 28
            Case "Complete"
                .Color = 55
            Case "Future Works"
                .Color = 53
            Case Else
                .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

I updated it slightly as still not working. The article I used below.

[Excel VBA: automatically adjust tab colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835129/excel-vba-automatically-adjust-tab-colour)

It won't be seen as a macro whilst I have "ByVal Target As Range" between () on the first line. But if I remove it it doesn't work.

It did work correctly once but then didn't change the colour of the cell after and threw up an error (this was a couple of hours ago now, so can't remember the message sorry).

It is probably something very basic, but alas so is my knowledge.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?.

**************EDIT/UPDATE**********************

Current code courtesy of Darren:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("B1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        With ActiveSheet.Tab
               Select Case Target
                Case "In Progress"
                    .Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
                Case "Held"
                    .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                Case "Parked"
                    .Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
                Case "Complete"
                    .Color = RGB(128, 0, 128)
                Case "Future works"
                    .Color = RGB(153, 0, 167)
                Case "scrapped"
                    .Color = RGB(194, 24, 7)

                Case Else
                    .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End Select
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

The tab colours do change, but not for "In Progress", "Future works", or "scrapped", the rest work fine?. I have changed the RGB values incase it is those colours, but it's still the same?. No colour values make these change, and the text going into the box is right as I have now added this as a data validation too (using a list on another tab). I complete the drop down now, and for 3 of the 6 it works fine???.

Comment: You're not using a [With..End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) block so your `.Color` lines don't know what they're referring to.  It should probably have something like `With ActiveSheet.Tab`

Comment: Added, tab changes to white, nothing else.

Comment: re: *'update tab colours based on b1 as well.i.e if in progress B2 goes green, so does that tab.'* What contains *'in progress'*, B1 or B2?

Comment: What do you mean by "It won't be seen as a macro whilst..."?

Comment: @FreeMan very literally it does nothing with that syntax in place. And I do mean nothing, it's not see as a macro, can't run it, f8 through it, nothing.

Comment: Ah! With a parameter, you have to call it from somewhere else. The VBE doesn't give you the option to provide parameters to a `Sub`/`Function` that requires them. You would need a line of code elsewhere like: `tabcolour_Change(myRange)`. You would execute that one with `F8` and it would step into the `tabcolour_Change` routine.

Comment: What do you mean "tabcolour"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do it - both use the `Change` event to monitor when a value is updated on a worksheet.
The `Intersect` command checks that the range `B2` is being changed.

You can either add this code to each sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("B2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        With Target.Parent.Tab
            Select Case Target
                Case "In Progress"
                    .Color = 43
                Case "Held"
                    .Color = 6
                Case "Parked"
                    .Color = 28

                Case Else
                    .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End Select
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

or you can add this code to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Sh.Range("B2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        With Sh.Tab
            Select Case Target
                Case "In Progress"
                    .Color = 43
                Case "Held"
                    .Color = 6
                Case "Parked"
                    .Color = 28

                Case Else
                    .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End Select
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: a) A Worksheet_Change can be triggered when that worksheet is not the activesheet; particularly through VBA. [edit] b) I think those are ColorIndex colours, not .Color colours.

Comment: @ user10735198 Was about to say "but it will still update the correct cell".... then realised what you were talking about.  Good point - I'll update my code.

Comment: I must be missing something. "ByVal Target As Range" in the top line prevents me running it, quite literally nothing happens, can't even use F8. How do I get around this? Should I have a certain reference enabled?.

Comment: You can't run these as a normal macro - they respond to events on the worksheet.  When you change a value on the sheet the code will fire automatically and `Target` will be a reference to the cell you just changed.  If you put a breakpoint on a line of code it should stop there and then you can `F8` through it (or write `Debug.Assert False` somewhere in the code to make it pause at that point).

Comment: If it still doesn't appear to be doing anything try opening the `Immediate` window in the VBA environment (Ctrl+G to open Immediate window if it's not already) and type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in there (they should be enabled already though - only get disabled by the `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Comment: [Worksheet Object Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/worksheet-object-events) for further reading.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook cheers. I have added the code per tab with the belief the tab colour would be based on the action of completing B2, but still no joy. The tab has changed to black and won't turn to any other colour.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook checked the immediate window and entered it fine, still nothing. Stays white now.

Comment: I tried with the values in my code - they did change, but not a lot.  When I tried `.Color = RGB(255,0,0)` it definitely changed to a red tab.  Maybe try RGB colours instead?  And you're adding the `Worksheet_Change` event just to the sheet?  I think `Workbook_SheetChange` in `ThisWorkbook` takes precedent.  Is the code firing when you make the change?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I tried RGB in one of my many attempts, but it seems to be doing "something" now. However not all of the options are giving a colour, or if I move the colours through the VB it doesn't affect the cell i.e if I set "In Progress" to (255, 0, 0) or (153, 0, 153) it will still come out red?.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook all sorted now. I added data validation and it all boiled down to have a lower case letter. Changed those and it kicked into life. Thanks for the help!.

Comment: Good stuff.   Was just trying to figure out what could be going wrong.  Didn't think about the case.  You could change the `Select Case` line to `Select Case LCase(Target)` to force everything to lowercase before making the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim myTab As Object
        Set myTab = ActiveSheet.Tab
        With myTab
             Select Case Range("$b$2").Value
            Case "In progress"
                .ColorIndex = 43
            Case "Held"
                .ColorIndex = 6
            Case "Scrapped"
                .ColorIndex = 3
            Case "Parked"
                .ColorIndex = 28
            Case "Complete"
                .ColorIndex = 55
            Case "Future Works"
                .ColorIndex = 53
            Case Else
                .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End Select
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also did nothing, tab colours did not change. Darren's is almost working, but it seems to only let 3 of the colours work ?????